# How to package and run Windows Help (.chm) file in a Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, jar, chm

I'm making a Swing application that will only run on Windows and I want to package everything into a single .jar file.  I want to include a .chm help file in the JAR and be able to launch it from clicking a `JMenuItem` marked "Help" or "Contents" (I already have a working understanding of creating  `AbstractAction` subclasses).  How can I programmatically open a .chm file from a JAR file?

Comment: Maybe `Desktop#open()`?

Comment: @trashgod I'm guessing you mean http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29.  I suppose you would have to treat an `InputStream` as a `File` somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Desktop`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/desktop-api-142259.html) provides an `open()` method. You'll probably have to retrieve the `.chm` as an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) and park it at a known location in the file system.

Comment: Maybe if the OP distributes the `JAR` as a zip file, the jar and chm can be in the same directory and thus eliminating the need for embedded resource ? :)

Comment: @Little Child, I was considering that, but there is the possibility that somebody will end up just taking the JAR with them and then missing the CHM.  I suppose a slightly lazy workaround would be to copy the CHM to some place on disk if it can't be found at runtime, but I still want a one-file solution if possible.

Comment: @LittleChild": Good idea. My only reservation would be mission creep on the _Windows only_ requirement. I'd at least leave hooks for a _strategy pattern_.

Comment: @trashgod You mean create a cross-platform help file ? :)

Comment: @LittleChild: I don't know if `.chm` can be made cross-platform; I usually load embedded HTML in a `JEditorPane`. Edit: OSX know locations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14233171/230513).

Comment: There are cross-platform viewers for CHM like these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help#Use_in_non-Windows_applications.